# Extract nested JSON content from JSON with use of JSON Extractor in jMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have JSON content inside another JSON that I need to extract as it is, without parsing its contents:

```
{
    "id": 555,
    "name": "aaa",
    "JSON": "{\r\n  \"fake1\": {},\r\n  \"fake2\": \"bbbb\",\r\n  \"fake3\": \"eee\" \r\n}",
    "after1": 1,
    "after2": "test"
}
```

When I use JSON Extractor with JSON Path expression:

```
$.JSON
```

It returns:

```
"{  
    "fake1": {},  
    "fake2": "bbbb",  
    "fake3": "eee"
}"
```

when I need to get the raw string:

```
"{\r\n  \"fake1\": {},\r\n  \"fake2\": \"bbbb\",\r\n  \"fake3\": \"eee\" \r\n}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) instead of the JSON Extractor and use the following code:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).JSON

vars.put('rawString', org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(json))
```

You will be able to refer the extracted value as `${rawString}` where required.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson() is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.JSON))
```

Here data is your given JSON data.
At first, you have to extract your JSON/data. Then you have to stringify the JSON data using    JSON.stringify().
The confusing fact you have done here is that you named your key in the JSON object as "JSON".
In js when you extract a JSON object if there is another nested JSON object you will always get JSON data by just    data.key_name
where data is JSON data
key is for Nested JSON key

Comment: but this is about jMeter JSON Extractor, why should I use console.log() and if I should - where in jMeter?

Comment: JSON.stringify(data.JSON).             By using this you can get the data in given string format.